# apostrophe like and equal clause not working

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-real-escape-string, apostrophe

I have one `table` named `tags` and it contain entry which is as below.

`ID
  Name
      Created Date



 10
limit\'s
2013-06-27 05:18:35`

Now i want to search for `limit's` using query but could not search record.

**For what i have tried.**

```
'SELECT id FROM tags AS Tag WHERE name = "%'. urlencode($adTag) .'%" LIMIT 0,1'

'SELECT id FROM tags AS Tag WHERE name LIKE "%'. htmlspecialchars($adTag) .'%" LIMIT 0,1'

'SELECT * FROM tags AS Tag WHERE name LIKE "%'. $adTag .'%" OR REPLACE(name,'''','') LIKE "%'. $adTag .'%"'

'SELECT id FROM tags AS Tag WHERE name LIKE "%'. mysql_real_escape_string( stripslashes($adTag)) .'%" LIMIT 0,1'

'SELECT id FROM tags AS Tag WHERE name LIKE "%'. mysql_real_escape_string($adTag) .'%" LIMIT 0,1'
```

Where `$adTag` is coming dynamically and its value is `limit's`. Above are tried but none of that worked.

Let me know what i am doing wrong so i can correct mysql.

Thanks.

Comment: why are you not using `PDO` or `MySQLi`?

Comment: @JW웃 Thanks for suggestion but its nearly finishing stage and i can't roll back as i am using custom MVC and used mysql...and its in house project so its need not to be worry for `SQL Injection`

Comment: is there a backslash in the "`limit\'s`" **for the reason** or just by some mistake?

Comment: @YourCommonSense thanks for -1 but as i said it's not going to be lived as it will be used only in local lan...well this is not the discussion topic here...please do not comment off the topic..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after so many googleing work done i finally get this working.

below is the solution for me.

```
SELECT *
FROM tags
WHERE `name` = 'limit\\''s'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Its worked like charm. Hope this will help in future for other geeks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to search for `limit's`, you have to have `limit's` in your table.
So, first of all get rid of the erroneous backslash in the table entry.

The rest is as usual

```
$tag = $db->getOne('SELECT id FROM tags WHERE name = ?s', $adTag);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried recreating your db and searching, it needs 2 addslashes to appear on the results. I think MySQL escapes the first slash automatically.

```
addslashes(addslashes($adTag));
```

Comment: Yeah I wouldn't recommend it. You should consider removing the slashes from the data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM tags AS Tag WHERE name LIKE %". mysql_real_escape_string( stripslashes(urldecode($adTag))) ."% LIMIT 0,1
```

Comment: May I ask why this certain combination of various PHP functions were chosen?