# Single qoute in MongoDB document

Tags: php, mongodb

In my HTML page user enters a search query and send it via `GET`. In some of my mongodb documents there are fields that have `'` in their value. But when user enters a query that contains `'` no result is returned. I also used PHP `addslash` function without success. How should I place the query in `find` function?

```
$col->find(['word' => new MongoRegex('/^' . addslashes($term) . '/i')];
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17335746/apostrophe-like-and-equal-clause-not-working

Comment: @DipeshParmar My DBMS is noSQL.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem before 2 days and i have solved it using below query.

below is the solution for me.

```
SELECT *
FROM tags
WHERE `name` = 'limit\\''s'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

[**`SEE HERE`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17335746/apostrophe-like-and-equal-clause-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `htmlentities` instead of `addslashes`

```
$col->find(['word' => new MongoRegex('/^' . htmlentities($term, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . '/i')];
```

reference: [regular expression for single quote mark in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9494372/regular-expression-for-single-quote-mark-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 0):

The JS shell seems to require `'` be escaped as unicode `\x27` (see: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9494535/162228)), but the PHP driver should not require any special treatment. Consider the following example:

```
$m = new MongoClient();
$c = $m->test->foo;
$c->drop();
$c->insert(['x'=>"foo'bar"]);
$c->insert(['x'=>"foobar"]);
$r = $c->find(['x' => new MongoRegex("/^foo'/i")]);
var_dump(iterator_to_array($r));
```

This query matches only the first document, where `x` is `foo'bar`. If you run the script, you should see that document printed out.